# Intel RealSense with ROS 2

Tags: navigation, ros2, slam, realsense, realsense-camera

I am just getting started with Intel Real Sense integration with ROS2. When trying to install Intel real sense packages in ROS 2 Humble, [the official documentation](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/distribution_linux.md#installing-the-packages:%7E:text=Ubuntu%20LTS%20kernels%204.4%2C%204.8%2C%204.10%2C%204.13%2C%204.15%2C%204.18*%2C%205.0*%2C%205.3*%2C%205.4%2C%205.13%20and%205.15) says the supported kernel version of this package is only for 5.4 or less. On the contrary, by default, the kernel version of ROS2 humble in Ubuntu 22 is 6.

Please give some input on whether ROS2 Humble supports real-sense integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

In short, the Intel RealSense camera works with ROS 2. You are looking at the documentation of the `librealsense`, which may not be updated accordingly. Anyways, I strongly suggest installing the prebuilt package using `apt`.  Below is an example:

```
sudo apt install ros-<ROS_DISTRO>-librealsense2*
sudo apt install ros-<ROS_DISTRO>-realsense2-*
```

Please note that you may need to configure your Ubuntu repositories in order to install these packages. So, please look at [the official documentation](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros#--installation).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt solution.